# How to accept HTTP Post and call command line with parameters?

Tags: bash, http, rest

I would like to call VLC from the command line (bash) through another computer's http request. In this case one computer will act as a server and will call different options to VLC based upon the http params it receives and the other computer will simply act as a client as it sends different http requests to the server with VLC on it.

This can be asked as a general question. Accept and http request on a server and subsequently call a CLI on bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way of doing is this is to set up a CGI script on Apache or any other web server, and use GET requests.

If something tries to fetch `http://yourhost/cgi-bin/yourscript?doStuff`, your script will be invoked, and `$QUERY_STRING` will contain `doStuff`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo

if [[ $QUERY_STRING == doStuff ]]
then
    yourcommand --here
    echo "Thanks, your stuff is done. "
else
    echo "Unknown stuff to do. Here are my variables:"
    set
fi
```

Just be aware of which user your HTTP server runs your script as.